# send method function of a specific object to a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

The only way of using a method function in a thread i've seen so far is:

```
std::thread t1(&mymethod::myfunction, param1, param2, ...);
```

If I understand correctly, the above example calls the general function, but not from a specific object, that means that the function does'nt work based on the current state of the object.

So, how can I call the function using a specific object?

In this way, error C3867 occurs:

```
myclass myobj(param);
std:: thread t1(myobj.myfunction, param1, param2, ...);
```

this is what happened in my specific work:
I want to create a class that has functions of read and write to a text file, using threads (RW lock)
I have the following class:

```
class readersWriters{
private:
    /*... here are some mutexes to implement readers writers lock... doesn't matter*/
    string _fileName;

public:
    readersWriters(string fileName); //constructor
    /*...*/
    void readLine(int lineNumber); //lineNumber - line number to read
    void WriteLine(int lineNumber, string newLine);//lineNumber - line number to write
}
```

So in the main function, i create an object of the class...

```
readersWriters one("sample.txt");
```

If i create the thread calling the function as i did in the example, how does the function know from which text to read and write? here i'm not succeeding:

```
//thread that reads from "sample.txt" through object "one"
//thread that writes through object "one"
//etc.
```

how can I do in order for the thread to read and write in sample.txt, from the object "one"?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is simpler. Just pass the pointer to the object as your second argument. Like this:

```
std::thread t1(&mymethod::myfunction, &myobj, param1, param2, ...);
```

You can also pass the object by copy or wrap it in `std::ref`, which would be effectively the same as passing by address.

Keep in mind that when passing by pointer or `std::ref` you assume the responsibilty of making sure the object does not get destroyed while accessed from the spawned thread.

Comment: so i need to update my member functions for them to take the pointer as parameter right?

Answer (score 0):

In any case where you know how to solve something for a "free" function, but you have a member function of a specific object, you can create a "free" function using a lambda with closure:

```
struct foo                                                              
{   
   int bar(int i, int j)
    {   
        return i + j;
    }   
}   


int main()
{   
    foo f;
    auto cb = [&f](int i, int j) {
        return f.bar(i, j); 
    };  

    cb(2, 3); 

    return 0;
}
```

Note that you need to take care of the lifetime of the object the lambda is capturing.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use lambda here.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use lambda anywhere. Some might find it more intuitive.

Comment: Nope, it is much less intuitive.

Comment: I'm guessing that's a refutation of my "*some* might find it more intuitive". Forgive me for not being persuaded.

Comment: No, this is a result of the answer which does not answer the question at all, and have very remote resemblance to the OP's problem. Btw, since you can't say the same for my answer, your downvote is not warranted.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I think it does. Not very interested in continuing the discussion with you.

Comment: I do find this more intuitive, it may be because I'm think more Java-esque. where I might throw an anon class to delegate an actual call to an instance method.

Comment: @SGM1 Not very knowledgeable of Java, but keep in mind that you have scope issues and object lifetimes in C++. When you do something like this, you must somehow ensures that the object does not die before the thread terminates.

Comment: @SGM1, but that is just a Java limitation. This is why it's full of classes like ThreadCallback, SocketCallback, SomethingElseCallback, UnversalCallback - which are all the same and simply contain a single virtual function to be called in the event of the callback. In C++ we are free from this madness, thanks to function pointers, functional objects, templates, and yes, lambdas.

Comment: @SergeyA Changing the called function definition does not sound like a solution to me in most cases, especially when you can get away with using a wrapper, or  a lambda in this case. Now the OP did not use the correct parameter sequence so you answer is of course more valid. This is just a round about alternative :)